# AnkhSVN: Cannot checkout Subsolution due to existing "versioned" folder

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I am using Subversion since quite some time for Java-Development and I have setup a repository on my local NAS. Since I have a MSDN subscription via my company I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 to do a small project with .NET.

According to some "best-practices" my project folder looks like the following.

```
MySolution
main.sln
    Services
    services.sln
        Service A
            files
        Service A Test
            files

    View
        projectfiles

    Persistence
    persistence.sln
        PersistenceXml
            files
        PersistenceXml Test
            files
        PersistenceDB
            files
        PersistenceDB Test
            files
```

The idea is, that the main.sln only contains the projects for the application, meaning no test projects. The subsolutions, contain the project(s) and their corresponding testprojects.
I was able to put all those projects under versioncontrol with AnkhSVN, so I have the same structure there in my trunk. Commiting changes was also no problem.

Now I would like to check the this out on another machine. I was able to check out the main.sln which downloaded everything that was inside this solution. It skipped the services.sln, persistence.sln and all the test-projects. Until now everything is fine.

**Now, here comes the problem:** when I am tryting to check out the subsolution (eg. services.sln) I get an error, I think it was UnsupportedOperation. **I guess this happens because ankhsvn is tryting to download the folder  Service A again and create ist hidden .svn folder which is already present.** The only workaround I can think of by now is installing Tortoise SVN and check out the whole thing at once. It would be nicer though to have everything from within VS.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Is another client the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you attempt the checkout?

The easiest way to do the checkout with AnkhSVN is
File->Open->Subversion Project

Then you select the .sln file by browsing to the right Url.

In the next dialog you can select at which level you want to start the checkout and to which (empty) folder you want to checkout.

Once you have a working copy with all your files, you don't have to use the checkout operation again, but you can just open the .sln files in Visual Studio. (The files are already on your pc)

Comment: stupid me :-) I expected that after the first checkout, only the files (folder) for this solution are checked out. But instead it got everything (as you mentioned). Of course, then the second checkout (as I did in the first place) will result in an error since it already is there.